# how to create reusable and MCV-compatible form fields in extjs4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have some form fields and field sets and i want to reuse them in different views( Which may have different layouts and/or more fields).

I need a solution under which i dont have to repeat these form fields in every view i create and i want to reuse previously defined ones.What do you suggest for a MVC-based application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a very basic custom component that you can reuse in forms (it would go in your app/form/field folder with name InterestRate.js):

```
Ext.define('app.form.field.InterestRate', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.field.Number',
  alias:'widget.ratefield',

  minValue:0,
  step:0.05,
  fieldLabel:'Rate'
});
```

You could then use it in a form like this:

```
Ext.define('app.view.Quote', {
  extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
  requires:[
    'app.form.field.InterestRate'
  ],
  items:[
  {
    xtype:'ratefield'
  }    
  ]
});
```

You can make the component as complex as you want, such as a whole grid or a fieldcontainer with multiple items.

The question is, do you want its behaviour to be self-contained, or to be controlled by the controller of the main form?

Comment: Thanks for the fruitful answer.Please change `'ratefield'` to `xtype:'ratefield'`